# Storing a TimeDelta in my SQL Server database

Tags: python, sql-server

Table `Tasks` has 2 datetime columns, `StartDate` and `EndDate`. I used python to calculate the difference between these two, resulting in column `Time_Difference`. See below:

```
Tasks['Time_Difference'] = Tasks['EndDate'] - Tasks['StartDate']
Avg_Task_Duration = Tasks['Time_Difference'].mean()
```

Now, I want to store the `Avg_Task_Duration` value in a Stats table from my SQL Server.  It is of type `timedelta` and looks like this: *Timedelta('438 days 09:25:10')*

Therefore, I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to store a timedelta in my SQL Server? If yes, what data type should the column have?
2. If not, is there any other alternative?

Comment: I have, as a proof-of-concept, made a CLR data type based on .NET's `duration` before. It's fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support the ISO SQL standard [interval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/equivalent-ansi-sql-data-types) type. You could use `time` for intervals less than 24 hours but need to store the value in integer units (e.g. seconds) to store longer periods.